# PHP: Error in url after insert in data base

Tags: php, url

I have error when send data to database.

**First I have URL like:**

```
www.domain.com/container.php?fun=olmaa
```

and after send data, the URL is as below:

```
www.domain.com/container.php?fun=olmaa&sent=yes
```

But, when send again it looks like:

www.domain.com/container.php?fun=olmaa&sent=yes&sent=yes

Why insert `&sent=yes` again ??

My code is:

```
$url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('Location: '.$url."&sent=yes");
```

Thank You

Comment: If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is empty u need to append a question mark after the server_name

Comment: why are u using  $url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before appending sent param just check it already exist or not by `strpos`. Try this..

```
$url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$final_url = (strpos($url, '&sent=yes') == false) ? $url."&sent=yes" : $url;
header('Location: '.$final_url);
```

Or can use `parse_str`.

```
$url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
parse_str($url, $params);
$final_url = (!isset($params['sent'])) ? $url."&sent=yes" : $url;
header('Location: '.$final_url);
```

Comment: mmm, How can i delete `&sent=yes` if found it before send again an d create it

Comment: @Kam, then can try this. `parse_str($url, $params);
if(isset($params['sent'])){
    $val = $params['sent'];
    $change_val = '&sent='.'your value';
    $final_url = str_replace('&sent='.$val, $change_val, $url);
}else{
    $final_url = $url."&sent=yes";
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second time you try to send the data the url that you are sending them is

```
   www.domain.com/container.php?fun=olmaa&sent=yes
```

So when you are building the new url in the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] already exists the &sent=yes part and you are appenting it again thats why you see it two times.
The code user3659034 gave solves it.